# 'dot' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: python, graphviz, decision-tree

```
from sklearn import tree
!pip install graphviz
decision_tree = tree.export_graphviz(dt_model,out_file='tree.dot',feature_names=X_train.columns,max_depth=2,filled=True)
!dot -Tpng tree.dot -o tree.png
```

Error

```
'dot' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

How to solve this?

Comment: Install [Graphviz](https://graphviz.org/).